# Replace a lookup table with machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, regression, prediction, implementation, data-augmentation

I have a lookup table with 2 input columns and 2 output columns. I want to replace it with a value function such that with a given input pair, the function can give the output pair with minimal error. The function will replace the LUT in an embedded system with minimal memory.

For training, I have a **very small dataset with only 40 rows**. Now, I am bit confused about whether to try regression techniques or behavioral cloning (from imitation learning) because my objective is to mimic the LUT as closely as possible.

I am a novice user of machine learning techniques and could not find simple starting examples for this type of table learning problems. Is there any? If it is infeasible then please also tell me.

Comment: welcome to Datascience SE community.
A couple of questions in regards to the OP. 1. Do you plan to use the LUT (apart from the 40 rows dataset) for mapping unseen input pair to the already existing output pair. If yes, then would the unseen input pair be very similar to the existing input pair and then new unseen pair would be mapped to one of the existing output columns. 2. Could you please share your dataset in order to understand the problem better.

Comment: Agree with @Polymath - think we need more context or examples of the data

Comment: Answers to Polymath's query (see below): 1.Yes, but the unseen input pairs will be very similar to the existing input pairs with small deviations. Even able to predict the known pairs by a function will be helpful.
2. Unfortunately, the dataset is proprietary. I am even not sure whether I can share it publicly with obfuscation. However, I can give some more detail info: (1) output values are picked from a fixed range of values (2) output rows can have same values for different input pairs (3) input 1 is distinct for each row, input 2 is one of the 10 possible values. However not all possible c

Comment: @JA974 please refrain from posting Answers that do not attempt to answer the question.  When you have 20 reputation you can [talk in chat](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat), and at 50 reputation you will be able to [comment on other people's posts](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) (you can always comment on your own posts and answers to your questions).